# Non negative operator which is positive on a dense subset

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let $\mathcal H$ be a separable Hilbert space. Assume that $Q$ is a non-negative compact self-adjoint operator $\mathcal H\to\mathcal H$.

Assume there is a dense subspace $U$ of $\mathcal H$ such that, for all non-zero $x\in U$
$$\langle Qx,x\rangle >0.$$

Can I claim that $U$ is positive on the whole space $\mathcal H$, i.e., for any non-zero $x\in\mathcal H$, $\langle Qx, x\rangle>0$?

I think that all I need to prove is that the range of $Q$ is dense in $\mathcal H$, since in this case the compactness and self-adjointness of $Q$ imply that $Q$ is injective and so, since it is even non-negative, it must be positive.

EDIT: I think the property is false, since any dense subset $U$ that does not contain the nullspace $N$ of $Q$, would satisfy the property that $\langle Qx,x\rangle >0$ if $x\in U$. Now is there always a subspace $U$ such that $U\cap N = \{0\}$? I guess so...

Comment: Do you know that for a compact self-adjoint operator you can always find an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ (since $\mathcal{H}$ is separable) and scalars $\lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$Q(x) = \sum \lambda_n \langle x, e_n\rangle e_n\,?$$

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, but how does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be a proper dense subspace of $H$   and let $e_0$ be a unit vector not in $U$.  Consider an orthonormal basis
$\{e_n\}_{n\in {\bf N}}$ which includes the chosen vector $e_0$ and   let $T$ be the compact operator specified by
$$
  T(e_n) = \left\{\matrix{
  0, & \text{ if } n=0, \cr
  e_n/n, & \text{ if } n>0.
}\right.
  $$
Since the kernel of $T$ coincides with $\mathbb Ce_0$, we see that the restriction of $T$ to $U$ is injective. So, for
every nonzero $x$ in $U$, one has that
$$
  \langle T^2(x), x\rangle  = \|T(x)\|^2 > 0.
  $$
However, since
$$
  \langle T^2(e_0), e_0\rangle  = 0,
  $$
we see that $Q:=T^2$ is not positive.